# Define a Hierarchy Json Structure

Tags: javascript, json, hierarchy

i have a web service that returns a json from a select on a db.
The problem is that this kind of object is a part of a hierarchy structure where every child is wired with the parent with a field called "idCdcParent".
The root element is where the idCdcParent is null.
In this case Roma,Milano and Napoli are the root element.
This is the json :

```
[{

  "idCdc": "2",
  "cdcName": "Roma",
  "order": "1",
  "isUsed": "false"
}, {

  "idCdc": "17",
  "idCdcParent": "5",
  "cdcName": "testGP",
  "order": "1",
  "isUsed": "false"
}, {

  "idCdc": "5",
  "idCdcParent": "2",
  "cdcName": "Progetti",
  "order": "2",
  "isUsed": "false"
}, {

  "idCdc": "18",
  "idCdcParent": "5",
  "cdcName": "testGPS",
  "order": "2",
  "isUsed": "false"
}, {

  "idCdc": "3",
  "cdcName": "Milano",
  "order": "4",
  "isUsed": "false"
}, {

  "idCdc": "7",
  "idCdcParent": "3",
  "cdcName": "l",
  "order": "4",
  "isUsed": "false"
}, {

  "idCdc": "4",
  "cdcName": "Napoli",
  "order": "5",
  "isUsed": "false"
}, {

  "idCdc": "9",
  "idCdcParent": "4",
  "cdcName": "cccc",
  "order": "6",
  "isUsed": "false"
}]
```

and i would like that it will be an json with an hierarchy structure where the field "idCdcParent" refers to the id of the parent object.
like this :

```
[{

    "idCdc": "2",
    "cdcName": "Roma",
    "order": "1",
    "isUsed": "false",
    "children": [{

        "idCdc": "5",
        "idCdcParent": "2",
        "cdcName": "Progetti",
        "order": "2",
        "isUsed": "false"
      },
      {

        "idCdc": "17",
        "idCdcParent": "5",
        "cdcName": "testGP",
        "order": "1",
        "isUsed": "false"
      }
    ]
  },
  {

    "idCdc": "5",
    "idCdcParent": "2",
    "cdcName": "Progetti",
    "order": "2",
    "isUsed": "false"
  },
  {

    "idCdc": "3",
    "cdcName": "Milano",
    "order": "4",
    "isUsed": "false",
    "children": [{
      "idCdc": "7",
      "idCdcParent": "3",
      "cdcName": "l",
      "order": "4",
      "isUsed": "false"
    }]
  },
  {
    "idCdc": "4",
    "cdcName": "Napoli",
    "order": "5",
    "isUsed": "false",
    "children": [{


      "idCdc": "9",
      "idCdcParent": "4",
      "cdcName": "cccc",
      "order": "6",
      "isUsed": "false"
    }]
  }
]
```

In javascript is that possible?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is possible, just go over the array and built up a lookup table for the ids:

```
const byID = {};

for(const el of array) 
  byId[el.idCdc] = el;
```

Now that you got the lookup table its easy to go over the nodes, and turn them into an hierarchy:

```
let root;

for(const el of array) {
  if(el.idCdcParent) {
     const parent = byID[el.idCdcParent];
     if(!parent.children) parent.children = [];
     parent.children.push(el);
  } else {
     root = el;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the array of entities into a tree using a **recursive function**.  This method creates a **new array** of hierarchical entities, and the original is not modified--that may be a plus or a minus, depending on your particular use-case:

```
function make_tree(treeable_entities) {
  function TreeNode(entity) {
    const children = get_children(entity.idCdc);
    const new_entity = Object.assign({}, entity);
    new_entity.children = children; 
    return new_entity;
  }

  function get_children(ofIdentifier) {
    return treeable_entities.filter(entity => entity.idCdcParent === ofIdentifier).map(TreeNode);
  }

  const is_root = (entity) => entity. idCdcParent === undefined;
  return treeable_entities.filter(is_root).map(TreeNode);
};
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: this recursive function will handle an infinite amount of parent -> child levels, if the data from your database has multiple parent->child relationships.

Comment: Did this help you?  Did you get your parent -> child relationships working the way you wanted?